# Trying to get references in order of text but everything I try does not seem to change anything

Tags: bibtex, natbib

document

```
 \documentclass{tudelft-report}

 \usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}
 \bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}

 \begin{document}


 \bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
 \bibliography{report}


 \end{document}
```

report.bib

```
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    % A part of the report.bib doc
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

     @article{Guo2018,
     abstract = {Alkoxy},
     author = {Guo, Jing Jing and Hu, Anhua and Zuo, Zhiwei},
     doi = {10.1016/j.tetlet.2018.04.060},
     file = {:Users/gebruiker/Documents/BEP/Papers/ Photocatalytic          alkoxy radical-mediated transformations.pdf:pdf},
     issn = {18733581},
     journal = {Tetrahedron Letters},
     keywords = {Alkoxy radical,C–H functionalization,Hydrogen atom          transfer,Photoredox catalysis,$\beta$-Scission},
     number = {22},
     pages = {2103--2111},
     title = {{Photocatalytic alkoxy radical-mediated          transformations}},
     volume = {59},
     year = {2018}
     }
     @article{Liu2010,
     abstract = {Generation-4 polyamidoamine (PAMAM).},
     author = {Liu, Huajie and T{\o}rring, Thomas and Dong, Mingdong and Rosen, Christian B. and Besenbacher, Flemming and Gothelf, Kurt V.},
     doi = {10.1021/ja109677n},
     file = {:Users/gebruiker/Documents/BEP/Papers/DNA-Templated Covalent Coupling of G4 PAMAM Dendrimers.pdf:pdf},
     issn = {00027863},
     journal = {Journal of the American Chemical Society},
     number = {51},
     pages = {18054--18056},
     title = {{DNA-templated covalent coupling of G4 PAMAM          dendrimers}},
     volume = {132},
     year = {2010}
     }
     @article{Sioda1968,
     abstract = {The visible spectra of the free radical.},
     author = {Sioda, R. E.},
     doi = {10.1021/j100853a007},
     file = {:Users/gebruiker/Documents/BEP/Papers/Electrolytic Oxidation of 9,10-Diphenylanthracene and Properties of Its Free Radical Cation and Anion.pdf:pdf},
     issn = {00223654},
     journal = {Journal of Physical Chemistry},
     number = {7},
     pages = {2322--2330},
     title = {{Electrolytic oxidation of 9,10-diphenylanthracene and properties of its free radical cation and anion}},
     volume = {72},
     year = {1968}
     }
```

Ive tried using biblatex, natbib, bibliographystyle{ieetr} but nothing changes it going from alphabetical order. Could there be something wrong with my bibtex file that ive used Mendely to make in a report.bib file?

Comment: Thank you I have edited my post

Comment: thanks oops but you have removed too much, the document has no \cite so will generate no bibliography, please make it show the problem of having them in the wrong order

Comment: I get `! LaTeX Error: File \`tudelft-report.cls' not found.` can you show the problem with `report.cls` ? if not and it is specific to that class please provide a link.

Comment: you have two bibliograhystyle commands so bibtex makes the error `Illegal, another \bibstyle command---line 5 of file cc507.aux` and does not do anything useful

Answer (score 2):

If I modify your source so it uses `report` class, only has one `\bibliography` command, and has some `\cite` to test then I get

[image]

which shows the references in order of citation not alphabetic order.

```
\documentclass{report}

 \usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}
 \bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}

 \begin{document}


first cite:   \cite{Sioda1968}

second cite:     \cite{Guo2018}


 \bibliography{report}


 \end{document}
```

If you are seeing a different behaviour please edit the question to show a test file that demonstrates the wrong order.

Comment: Thank you. It does work when I change my file to report instead of tudelft-report. However it does not work when I keep my document in tudelft-report, I do not understand why it is like that

Comment: @Catherine well since we don't have tudelft hard to say:-) If there is a public link to it. add that, or if it is small enough, add it to a code block in your question. probably it specifies a bibliographystyle within the class, but hard to say....